# react-native-firebase) fcm tokens are not issued, randomly

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have launched my application using `@react-native-firebase/messaging` and I'm in some tricky situation now.
My app saves fcm tokens in database to target specific users and send notifications to them. And it saves tokens into database when user opens the app, to ensure that every user has their own token (prepare for any issue such as a network error).
What is wierd, is that about 11,000 users have registered in my app, but about 3,000 users does not have their token. There is no database issues, and this randomly happens even on exactly same device (regardless of whether it is iOS or Android). I'm quite sure that there won't be as many as 3,000 people who denied permission or who deleted my app.

I wonder if anyone else had the same problem as me.
Below is my simplified codes where using `messaging().getToken()`. Is there any problem in my code?

(+) I was using version `^11.5.0`, and I updated it into `^12.0.0` in last week.

```json
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^11.5.0",
```

(++) On other devices that successfully saved their token in database, everything works perfectly.

---

##### App.tsx

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <PushHandler />
      <Navigation /> 
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

##### PushHandler.tsx

```js
export const PushHandler: React.FC = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState)
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<FirebaseMessagingTypes.AuthorizationStatus>()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check AppState, and when app has come to the foreground, check permission
    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: AppStateStatus) => {
      if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
        messaging()
          .hasPermission()
          .then(authStatus => setHasPermission(authStatus))
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState
    }
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange)

    return AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    handleTokenPermission()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasPermission === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || hasPermission === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL) {
      saveDeviceToken()
    }
  }, [hasPermission])

  const handleTokenPermission = async () => {
    try {
      // Check whether permission allowed
      const authStatus = await messaging().hasPermission()
      const enabled = authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL
      if (enabled) {
        setHasPermission(authStatus)
      } else {
        // if permission already has been denied, move to settings
        if (authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.DENIED) {
          Alert.alert('check permission', undefined, [
            { text: 'cancel' },
            { text: 'settings', onPress: openSettings },
          ])
        }
        // else, request permission
        else {
          const authorized = await messaging().requestPermission()
          setHasPermission(authorized)
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  const saveDeviceToken = async () => {
    try {
      messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then(async fcmToken => {
          console.log('PUSH TOKEN: ', fcmToken)
          await saveTokenToDatabase({ token: fcmToken }) // This is the function I save fcm token into my database
        })

      return messaging().onTokenRefresh(async token => {
        await saveTokenToDatabase({ token })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  return null
}
```

Comment: Very difficult to know what is exactly wrong code seems fine but why do you have to check app is in foreground?

Comment: to get permission and token immediately when users who opened setting and allowed permission get back to my app. (from here
`Alert.alert('check permission', undefined, [ { text: 'cancel' }, { text: 'settings', onPress: openSettings }])`)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks okay you probably need to log response after you send token to the database, that way you will track each instance with the different devices

Comment: actually, server engineer says `saveTokenToDatabase` (the function which saves token into database) does not have any error logs :(